# Cobrança Azure, em reais ou dólar?

Tags: microsoft-azure

Vasculhei todo o site do Azure e encontrei diversas informações divergentes sobre a moeda utilizada na cobrança.

Na calculadora diz:

> Importante: o preço em reais (R$) é apenas uma referência. Esta é uma
>   transação internacional e, como tal, seu preço está sujeito a taxas de
>   câmbio e à inclusão de impostos como IOF. Não será emitida uma eNF.

Na página http://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/pricing/faq/ existe um tópico que diz que a moeda R$ pode ser utilizada.

Sendo assim, os serviços cobrados pelo azure são em dólar ou reais?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Quando você contrata um serviço por $100,00 por exemplo e a cotação do dólar está em R$3,15 como hoje, você irá pagar R$315,00.

Se na próxima fatura a cotação do dólar baixar para R$2,50 e a sua contratação ainda for de $100,00 você pagará R$250,00.

Você contrata em dólar, mas paga em real se você assim escolher.

Acho que é isto que o site do Azure quer dizer com a utilização da moeda em real.

Utilizamos a azure assim aqui na empresa. Com a variação do dólar o valor em reais também varia.

Comment: Mesma prática da AWS, que pena! Fica difícil manter um serviço que você não sabe quanto vai pagar no final do mês, obrigado Richard

Comment: Se você quer um pagamento em real que não dependa da variação do dólar, tente pegar um servidor nacional. Assim você tem mais segurança em relação a quanto irá pagar.

Comment: O ultimo comentário do Richard diz tudo, o serviço é americano, a culpa não é do AWS ou Azure, a questão é cambio, isto é uma questão de que cada país tem sua moeda e o mercado sempre muda, mesmo aqui no Brasil, hoje 100 reais podem valer bastante e amanhã não valer muito, o numero não muda, mas o "mercado" sim.

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft Azure possui tabela de preços em REAIS aqui no Brasil.

Mas quando vai cobrar no seu cartão (se for esse seu métodos de pagamento) irá pegar o valor em REAL, e converter para DOLARES no cambio do dia.

Isso porque, o Banco Central do Brasil, não permite que empresas estrangeiras façam cobrança em moeda nacional.

Exemplo:

Sua conta deu R$ 50,00 no final de um mês.
O dólar no dia do crédito no cartão estava a R$ 3,2510.
A Microsoft irá cobrar no seu cartão 50,00 / 3,2510 = US$ 15.38

AÍ, sua operador de cartão de crédito irá fazer o oposto, mas no dia do vencimento da fatura:

Microsoft te cobrou US$ 15.38
O dólar no dia do vencimento da fatura estava R$ 3,2865
A operadora do cartão irá cobrar de você 15.38 x 3,2865 = R$ 50,55

AÍ, o governo vem babando e te lasca um imposto chamado IOF (Imposto sobre Operações Financeiras) no valor de 6,38%, e te cobra na mesma fatura R$ 55,55 * 0,0638 = R$ 3,23

No final, um serviço que a Microsoft te cobrou R$ 50,00, por causa do Banco Centra e dos impostos do nosso governo, você irá pagar R$ 53,78

Simples né? :)

=> No final, a Microsoft irá te cobrar em DOLARES.

Answer (score 1):

A informação correta é esta mesmo, os valores em R$ no site do Azure são apenas como referências e sim você será cobrado com base na taxa do dólar do dia + IOF caso esteja pagando no cartão, PORÉM existem algumas alternativas que podem te ajudar a ter um maior controle dos gastos ou reduzir alguns custos sem alterar a arquitetura do seu ambiente já desenvolvido.

1 - Caso hoje você esteja no modelo PAYG (pay-as-you-go) e pagando pelo cartão de crédito a lógica de pagamento é a mencionada acima, porém você pode requisitar para pagar via INVOICE o que ao menos fará com que você não tenho o custo de IOF, ou seja, uma redução de 6,38% na sua fatura simplesmente entrando em contato com o suporte de Billing e solicitando para pagar via Boleto/Invoice. Para abrir um tiket para o time de Billing basta fazê-lo pelo Portal do Azure ou ainda utilizar este link http://support.microsoft.com/oas/?prid=15470&ln=en-us

2 - A outra alternativa será mudar o modelo da sua conta de PAYG para o modelo OPEN, onde no modelo OPEN ao invés de você pagar a fatura após o uso você compra os créditos em unidades correspondentes a US$100 e consegue acompanhar diretamente pelo Painel do Azure, caso tenha necessidade de incluir mais créditos e incluí-lo na sua conta. Para efetuar tal compra basta entrar em contato com qualquer Revenda Microsoft.
Observação: Vale lembrar que neste modelo todos os impostos voltados à serviços online já serão cobrados e ainda você terá uma NF, coisa que não existe no modeloo PAYG por você estar pagando diretamente para a Microsoft Corp.

3 - Ainda existe a opção de contratos por volume, ou também conhecido como EA, onde basicamente é feita uma projeção do seu consumo no período de 1 ano e é efetuado um contrato para este período de forma ré-paga. Desta forma o cliente não sofre com as variações cambiais e ainda conta com algumas vantagens no gerenciamento de multiplas assinaturas e controle de gastos. Para maiores informações basta liga para o 0800 que aparece no site http://azure.microsoft.com/ que o time que os atender irá ajudá-los a precificar, montar todo o projeto e colocá-los em contato com as empresas que vazem este tipo de contrato.